# Aplicação Web e token A3 sem instalações locais

Tags: c#, web-service, asp.net-core, certificado-digital

Meu objetivo é um sistema web que sirva como ponte entre um serviço do governo e o usuário, abstraindo o acesso e a troca de dados.
O usuário acessaria meu sistema web e poderia realizar ações, como enviar documentos assinados digitalmente, para um serviço do governo (como um xml).
Porém pra realizar esse envio, o WebService do governo, disponibiliza classes com métodos de acesso e nessas classes existem algumas propriedades que precisam ser preenchidas, como a propriedade `ClientCertificate.Certificate` nela eu tenho que atribuir um objeto tipo `X509Certificate2` com o objeto do certificado do cliente.

Consegui fazer usando A1, o usuário faz upload do A1 e insere a senha, com o arquivo do A1 eu consigo instanciar o objeto `X509Certificate2` e atribuí-lo a respectiva propriedade na classe responsável pelos dados da conexão com WebService do governo.
Não sei como faria com A3, já que não daria pra fazer upload da chave publica/privada. Já vi que o browser consegue acessar a lista de certificados na máquina, mas não sei como faria pra instanciar um objeto `X509Certificate2` no servidor usando esse método, nem se isso é viável pra uma aplicação web.

Resumindo, minha dúvida é:
**É possível (ou viável) uma aplicação web acessar as chaves e os dados locais de um token A3 pra se comunicar com um WebService do governo?**

Dúvidas extras:
*O acesso do browser aos certificados na store do usuário é feito de que forma? Como eu preencheria um objeto `X509Certificate2`?*

Answer (score 1):

Diego, eu passo basicamente pelo mesmo problema. Depois de pesquisar muito, optei por usar somente certificados A1 nos casos de sistema na nuvem.

Minha conclusão foi a seguinte: Se o minha API ou serviço está rodando no servidor e o certificado A3 está no cliente, para cada chamada o cliente sempre terá que me enviar o certificado. Com isso eu me limito a trabalhar somente com requisições de entrada. Não poderia, por exemplo, adicionar um serviço que faça uma determinada operação que dependa do certificado em um *timer* (ou alguma rotina - nesse caso foi para aplicação no serviço de notas fiscais do destinatário da NF-e).

Dependendo da necessidade, você pode fazer um sistema desktop *tryon* ou um serviço do windows no cliente que faça essas chamadas, com isso você conseguiria sim utilizar o certificado A3 (inclusive setando a senha automaticamente quando for o caso). Porém, o problema de um *timer* como citei acima ficaria nesse app no cliente.

Já utilizei uma forma de se criar um "servidor" de certificado para a rede local do cliente. Ele possuía um certificado A3 e vários usuários faziam a transmissão de NF-e, com isso toda regra de transmissão eu coloquei nesse *comunicador de NF-e*

Trabalhando com A1 eu o deixo salvo no servidor web, no meu caso salvei em formato string na base64. E tenho autonomia total sobre ele.

Bom eu não solucionei nada pra você(haha), mas como estamos no mesmo barco vale a troca de experiência.

Comment: _"não solucionei nada pra você"_ Meu irmão, esse relato ajudou demais e me deixou muito mais próximo da solução mais prática pro meu problema, agradeço muito por dividir sua experiência. Pro A1 eu fiz a mesma coisa que você, fica super tranquilo. Acho que pro A3 vou acabar tendo que fazer uma aplicaçãozinha windows forms mesmo, ou algo do tipo, que o cliente instala local e eu crio uma logica de comunicação entre o servidor e a aplicação.

Comment: @DiegoPenha valeu parceiro! Se puder ajudar estou a disposição. Abraço.